# django: how to know if a model is created with a m2m field not None

Tags: django, django-models

So basically I am trying to override the save method of a model to tell if a certain non-required field, which is a m2m field, is specified. If so, then update one of its own Boolean field to True. Currently I have something like this:

```
class Flag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Model(models.Model):
    BooleanField = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    m2mField = models.ManyToManyField(Flag)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            if Model.objects.filter(id = self.id, m2mField = None).exists():
                Model.objects.filter(id = self.id).update(BooleanField = True)
```

And this is not working for me now. I don't really care what is in the m2m field, just trying to know if that field is specified by user when creating this instance.

TIA

Edit: I update with a more realistic definition.

Comment: Please make your example code a little more complete with the actual model name the m2m field and the boolean field definitions. It is easier to help you if you supply realistic code.

Comment: You should filter on `your_m2m_field__isnull=True`

Comment: It would be easier to understand your problem if we had model definition code.

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried to add more details in the update, and I tried to filter on isnull, but still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking if the m2mField count is more than 0, like so:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    BooleanField = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    m2mField = models.ManyToManyField(Flag, blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.BooleanField = True if self.pk is not None and self.m2mField.count() > 0 else False
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It would probably a good idea to pass the `blank=True` argument to the m2mField.